# Drupal 6 template - Better suggestion for change image path in preprocess?

Tags: image, templates, drupal, drupal-6, preprocessor

I have to change the template in one of Drupal [6 project](http://www.dobrasmlouva.cz/en).

On every "page" node type is stored an image in the CCK field. I have made new design template to change the the design through CSS. But now the customer demand is to change the images that are in CCK field named "field_obr" (one per node) only in my new design template. That he can switch the themes and the images will correspond with themes (current design = original images from CCK, new design = images from altered path from original CCK field path). Images names can be the same, only the directory changed.

Original images are stored in folder like:

```
sites/default/files/image1.jpg
sites/default/files/image2.jpg
...
```

I want to change in my new theme the path to an image to:

```
sites/default/files/new_img/image1.jpg
sites/default/files/new_img/image2.jpg
...
```

= to add the "/new_img" folder in the path before the image. (Or later path to my template file - thac I know how to, but I'm looking here for the principle.)

Template outputs the image as:

```
 <img  class="imagefield imagefield-field_obr" width="229" height="346" alt="" src="/sites/default/files/radek_home_0.jpg?1354577633" />
```

I have fond this solutions:

**First solution - change $content output through preg_replace()**

In the "node-page.tpl.php" to look in the $content throug preg_replace() function, find the path and change/add the string as I wish. - This is doable, but i feel that is not optimal solution to Drupal-flow.

**Second solution - using hook_page_alter() or hook_page_build() functions**

I have fount that the content of variables can be altered through using hook_page_alter() and hook_page_build() functions.

I put these functions to my "template.php" before phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) function, bud it seems that they do nothing:

```
function hook_page_build(&$page) {
//    print_r($page);
    $page['node']->field_obr['0']['filepath'] = "sites/default/files/new_img/radek_home_0.jpg";
    echo "Test function hook_page_build() has run";
}
```

Than i found in the docu, that these functions are for Drupal 7+ :-(

**Question:**
Can anyone explain me the best solution tho solve the situation described in the beginning? How to achieve it through the profi "Drupal way?"
Thank you.
Frantisek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some research and for Drupal 6 found single easy working solution for the described problem. It is the mentioned PHP [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) function located in the template `page.tpl.php`:

```
print preg_replace('#/sites/default/files/#', '/sites/default/files/_new/', $content);
```